# Code sample strangely indented?

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting

When viewing [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5229/4162) the shell transcript seems to be misindented, but when I edit the source it seems fine?

Comment: This is "the MathJax bug". MathJax is still enabled on meta for testing purposes. This won't happen if it's posted on main. The best fix is not to use dollar signs if possible.