# "Operation golf"

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a tag that can be used for an "operation golf" (for lack of a better phrase) challenge? Where the criteria is, for example, the number of *operators* and/or *library function calls* (e.g. `cos` or whatever) you use, rather than the character/byte count? (That's just an example, such a challenge would have much more clearly specified criteria.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [atomic-code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf). But be aware that challenges of this genre are very tricky to get right, because it's hard to define in an objective way, across all possible languages, what counts as a single operator (or token etc). And then there's the issue that many languages have some form of `eval`, so if the program contains too many tokens or operators, they'll just stuff it all in  a string.

These challenges usually work best when you can design a simple toy-language for everyone to use, which doesn't have these issues (e.g. only allow basic maths operations). [Here is a good example of that.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37188/8478)

If you mean "least number of operator/function *calls* at runtime", the tag you're looking for is [fewest-operations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fewest-operations). The same caveats as above apply.

Comment: Ah, so my next question was going to be whether or not I can limit the set of acceptable languages in the criteria, but then I see your comment about the toy language. So I can specify a pseudo-language as long as I make it clear? Very nice. And excellent example.

Comment: @JasonC If it's really simple (or mostly maths), it's fine if you make it a pseudo-language. If it gets a bit more complicated (or programmer-y, i.e. it has procedural constructs or something), it would be good if you provide a reference interpreter so it can be unambiguously determined whether answers are valid or not.

Comment: Do you think there'd be any interest in getting the community involved in designed a sort of "common" language that can be (optionally) used in such challenges, in the form of a citable meta post (for community input and documentation) and a reference interpreter? I realize this is off-topic, but before I take the time to even bother proposing it, I want to get a sense of whether it's completely off-base or not. Sort of an "official language of PPCG". I've got a pretty good idea that I think would suit challenges with varying criteria (including the limited operation example) well.

Comment: @JasonC Possibly. The same thing [has been done for fastest-code challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5134/8478).

Comment: Excellent precedent. That may be my mission this weekend. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonC I'd love to help you.  If you want, create a chat room, and [invite me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/117451/nathan-merrill) :)

Comment: @NathanMerrill I'm not going to dig in right this moment but I will definitely ping you in the next few days!